# SqlBulkInsert - How to set Fire Triggers, Check Constraints?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net, sqlbulkcopy

I'm performing a bulk insert with an ADO.NET 2.0 SqlBulkCopy object from a C# method into a MS SQL 2005 database, using a database user with limited permissions.  When I try to run the operation, I get the error message:

> Bulk copy failed. User does not have
>   ALTER TABLE permission on table
>   'theTable'. ALTER
>   TABLE permission is required on the
>   target table of a bulk copy operation
>   if the table has triggers or  check
>   constraints, but `'FIRE_TRIGGERS'` or
>   `'CHECK_CONSTRAINTS'` bulk hints are not
>   specified as options to the  bulk copy
>   command.

I read some documentation and created the bulk copy object with the constructor that lets me specify such things:

```
    SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"],
        SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers & SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints);
```

But this doesn't change anything - I get the same error message as before.  I tried fiddling with some of the other SqlBulkCopyOptions values but no luck.  I really thought this would fix the problem, am I missing something?

I tested the procedure after granting ALTER on the table to my user, and the operation succeeded.  However this is not an option for my situation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solved it!  Looks like I need a refresher on flags enums.  I was bitwise ANDing the enum values when I should have been ORing them.

```
SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers & SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints
```

evaluates to zero (which is equivalent to SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default.)

```
SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers | SqlBulkCopyOptions.CheckConstraints
```

Worked correctly and allowed the bulk insert to complete.

Comment: I didn't know these options existed but some creative searching got me here. Solved my issue with SqlBulkCopy into a table with triggers *without* having to give my SQL login ALTER TABLE permissions!

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities only, I'm sorry

SQL documentation for [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365(SQL.90).aspx) specifies 3 cases where ALTER TABLE is needed. You listed 2 of them. Is the KeepIdentity option being set, even if not needed?

Another option is that the trigger on the table is disabled already, confusing the issue. Use `ALTER TABLE dbo.SomeTable ENABLE TRIGGER ALL` to ensure enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the tips gbn, I tried them before I realized the answer (see below.)